# Can't expose web server using docker on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, go

I have a docker image that runs a webserver and I would like to access it from my local OSX, but I'm having issues.

I start the container with: `docker run -p 8000:8000 <container-name>`

and I can see log messages telling me that the local server is listening on `localhost:8000`

I am able to get a successful response from running:

`docker exec <IMAGE-ID> curl "http://localhost:8000/"`

Addresses I've tried on my local OSX are:

- `http://localhost:8000/`
- `http://<DOCKER-IP-172.17.0.2:8000/`

Neither of those work. Any suggestions?

- Container is built from `golang:1.8`
- Docker Version: `Version 17.03.1-ce-mac5 (16048)`
- MacOS Sierra: `10.12.4`
- Firewall is turned off for testing purposes

I've tried the same process on Ubuntu 16.04 and no luck their either.

Comment: Have you checked that your firewall isn't blocking it?

Comment: could you share the code for your server so I could test it locally?

Comment: Does your webserver listen only on `localhost:8000`? It's supposed to listen on `0.0.0.0:8000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer versions of docker use `vpnkit` on OSX to manage the port forwarding to the containers... you should allow vpnkit through your firewall if you want to expose the container ports.

Also, in your Go code, make sure to bind to `0.0.0.0` rather than `127.0.0.1` for your webserver code.

Comment: Still not working; I've turned my firewall off and restarted the docker container

Comment: That means that likely your code is listening on the localhost interface rather than the public interface of your container... Is your code binding to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Changing the binding to 0.0.0.0 worked rather 127.0.0.1!